# Маршрутизация с несколькими параметрами ASP.NET CORE

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

В приложении есть четыре кнопки dropdown. Варианты в выпадающем списке являются ссылками. Код одной из  них:

```
<li><a asp-controller="Aircrafts" asp-action="Compare" 
asp-route-vehicle1="@item.Id">@item.Name</a></li>
```

@item.Id переменная int

Метод контроллера принимающий значения

```
[HttpGet("compare/{vehicle1}/{vehicle2}/{vehicle3}/{vehicle4}")]
public IActionResult Compare(int vehicle1, int vehicle2, int vehicle3, int vehicle4)
{//код}
```

Маршрутизация:.

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
name: "FourParameters",
pattern: "controller=Aircrafts}/{action=Compare}/{vehicle1=0}/{vehicle2=0}/{vehicle3=0}/{vehicle4=0}");
```

В мой реализации метод контроллера вызывается только после клика на четвертом dropdown

Задача: При клике пользователя по сслыке в любом из dropdown, например по третьему, необходимо чтобы создался адресс aircrafts/compare/0/0/5/0 и вызвался метод в контроллере, если он кликнет по четвертому, то адресс должен быть aircrafts/compare/0/0/5/8 и т.д.

Comment: как в книге написано, так и делай

Comment: Зачем вы дублируете два типа маршрутизации?

Comment: @pavel-mayorov я думал, что в HttpGet указываются параметры, которые принимает контроллер, а в MapControllerRoute сам маршрут. Когда я пробовал указывать параметры только в HttpGet, то ссылка была только с одним параметром вместо четырех. Сейчас же все работает, но метод вызывается только после клика по четвертому drop-down. В этом и проблема с которой я обратился)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось, мое решение было хорошим.
Просто удалите параметры атрибута:

```
[HttpGet("compare/{vehicle1}/{vehicle2}/{vehicle3}/{vehicle4}")]



[HttpGet]
```

И все работает как ожидалось